# Solution to first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE, which I need to find a general solution for:

$$y'=\frac{2x^2y-xy^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2}{x^2-xy+y-1}$$

This doesn't seem to fit one of the categories of first-order ODE, which I know how to solve (I also tried to find an integrating factor to make it an exact equation but couldn't find one).

Would appreciate any help with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is this coming from?

Comment: Questions:  (a) why do we care about solving this equation? (b) would asymptotic solutions for small $x$ and large $x$ be good enough? (c) what boundary condition are you imposing? 

You may be able to construct an integrating factor which obeys a pde - See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/801091/integration-factor-first-order-nonlinear-ode?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The denominator is $(x-1)(x+1-y)$

So let set $u=x+1-y$ and hope for a simplification.

$\begin{align}\require{cancel}\cancel{1}-u'&=\dfrac{2x^2(x+1-u)-x(x+1-u)^2+(x+1-u)^2/2}{(x-1)u}\\\\
&=\dfrac{x^3+x^2/2+1/2+\cancel{xu}-xu^2-\cancel{u}+u^2/2}{(x-1)u}\\\\
\end{align}$

$\iff (1-x)(2uu')=(2x^3+x^2+1)+(1-2x)u^2$

Therefore if we set $v=u^2$ we get a linear ODE in $v$ which is solvable.

Answer (score 0):

A few steps $$y'=\frac{2x^2y-xy^2+\frac{1}{2}y^2}{x^2-xy+y-1}$$

$$y=z+x+1 \qquad \implies \qquad z'=-\frac{2 x^3+x^2+1+(1-2 x) z^2}{2 (x-1) z}$$
$$z=\frac u{2(x-1)}\qquad \implies \qquad 2 (x-1) u u'=(2 x+1) u^2-4 (x-1)^2 \left(2 x^3+x^2+1\right)$$
$$u=\sqrt v\qquad \implies \qquad (x-1) v'=(2 x+1) v-4 (x-1)^2 \left(2 x^3+x^2+1\right)$$

The homogeneous equation
$$ (x-1) v'=(2 x+1) v$$ is more than simple and then variation of the parameter to obtain the particular solution.

Answer (score -1):

Maple says this is an Abel equation of second kind and class B.
It finds the solutions
$$ y\left(x \right) = 
x +1 \pm \sqrt{c (x-1) {\mathrm e}^{2x}+(x+1)^2}
$$
where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: This seems more a comment than an answer : )